# Will 22 gauge wire work for Microphone cables?

Tags: equipment, cable

I accidentally bought some 22 AWG, balanced, shielded (Aluminum/Polyester Foil) wire. I've never seen audio cables use this small of a gauge before. Will this work for an XLR connector? Will it affect noise, interference, or bandwidth? Can it handle 48V phantom power?

(Is this the right SE for gear-related questions?)

Comment: Amazon has 22 gauge XLR cables… so it might. The trouble with ["gauge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_gauge) is it's a horrible old [US-only measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) these days that the rest of the world doesn't understand. The rest of the world went metric decades ago. Even the Brits have an [old system that's absolutely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_wire_gauge) so you really need to know **whose** gauge you mean.

Comment: They are AWG, the question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really the gauge size that you need to worry about for mic cables, chances are the wiring inside the microphone is a fraction of that size. I would be more concerned with the flexibility of the cable and things like whether the cable diameter is enough for the connector strain relief to sufficiently grab onto to be effective. My own experience would cause me to shy away from using the kind of cable you have described. There are a lot of different quality grades of microphone cable wire and I've found the less expensive ones actually cost more in maintenance and headaches. I know of no one who enjoys a cable failure just when the music and energy are starting to build in a performance. Its very difficult to recover that energy after you have to stop and replace a faulty cable and you can't really count on a cable to magically fix itself. I hope these pointers help you.

Answer (score 1):

This could work fine for fixed wiring. Or between a lapel mic amd a bodypack transmitter.  Probably not robust enough for a stage cable that will be trodden on and otherwise maltreated.

Ever looked inside a multi-way 'snake'? 22 and 24 gauge are standard.  Electrically it will be fine.